# Reading local text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to read test.txt through javascript and jquery in the HTML page textread.html stored in the same directory. But I get the following error:

Method 1 **jQuery Method**

---

jQuery error:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

---

jQuery:
`

```
$.getJSON('test.txt', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

`

---

Method 2 **javascript Method**

---

javascript error: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

---

javascript:

`

```
if (xmlhttp != null)    {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.txt",false); // the false makes this synchronous!
    xmlhttp.send();
    var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

`

---

I have also tried alternative code

I am not hosting this application as I will be deploying it using PhoneGap as mobile applications.

Please provide me with a solution to read file under these circumstances. 
As an alternative solution is HTML5 FileReader advisable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML 5 i found a really nice tutorial:

[Reading Files using HTML 5](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)

**Html:**

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

   <h1>Text File Reader</h1>
   <div>
      Select a text file: 
      <input type="file" id="fileInput">
   </div>
   <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function() {
   var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
   var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

   fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var textType = /text.*/;

      if (file.type.match(textType)) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function(e) {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
         }

         reader.readAsText(file);   
      } else {
         fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you could try using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'test.txt',
   success : function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   }
});
```